# How to add labels to the terminal nodes of a ctree (package party)?

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I created a binary classification tree using ctree. I would like each terminal node to contain the row names associated with that node. How can I accomplish this?

For example, for the dataset below, I would like the leftmost node to list the names of all those who are aged <23 (Abner to Abudemio) and the rightmost Abundiantus to Acelin respectively.

```
      names       age height young   
1     Abner       18   76.1   yes
2     Abraham     19   77.0   yes
3     Abram       20   78.1   yes
4     Abrasha     21   78.2   yes
5     Absalom     22   78.8   yes
6     Abudemio    23   79.7   yes
7     Abundiantus 24   79.9    no
8     Acacio      25   81.1    no
9     Acario      26   81.2    no
10    Accursius   27   81.8    no
11    Ace         28   82.8    no
12    Acelin      29   83.5    no
```

. [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one hacky solution. It involves very little modification in the original source code of the plotting functions from the `party` package. By reading the source code, I noticed that there is a `terminal_panel` which is calling `node_barplot` in case the outcome is a factor. (Everything is located in the `R/plot.R` function, if you have source package installed.) We can modify the later to display custom labels in the default bar chart.

Just issue the following command at R prompt:

```
fixInNamespace("node_barplot", pos="package:party")
```

and then, start adding what we want:

1. Add `labels = NULL, gp = NULL` to the existing list of arguments for that function.
2. Near the end of the function body, after `grid.rect(gp = gpar(fill = "transparent"))`, add the following lines:

   ```
   if (!is.null(labels)) {
     labs <- as.character(labels[ctreeobj@where==node$nodeID])
     len <- length(labs)
     x <- unit(rep(0.5, len), "npc")
     y <- unit(0.5:len/len, "npc")
     for (i in 1:len) 
       grid.text(labs[i], x=x[i], y=y[i], just="center", gp=gp)
   }
   ```

   Here, the key idea is to select labels corresponding to the selected node (`node$nodeID`), and we can grab this information from the slot `where` of the `ctree` object (this is a vector indicating in which node each case ended up). The `if` test is just to ensure that we can use the function as originally written. The `gp` argument can be used to change font size or color.

A typical call to the function would now be:

```
plot(cfit, tp_pars=list(labels=dfrm$names))
```

where `dfrm$names` is a column of labels from a data frame named `dfrm`. Here is an illustration with your data:

```
cfit <- ctree(young ~ age, data=a, 
              controls=ctree_control(minsplit=2, minbucket=2))
plot(cfit, tp_args=list(labels=a$names, gp=gpar(fontsize=8, col="darkgrey")))
```

[image]

<sub>(I have also tested this with the on-line example with the `iris` dataset.)</sub>